# Ref list listing arg instead of actual argument's text in a newcommand

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

What i'm trying to do is to set up a quick insert of a pdf at a default size with the new command `\zfh`.
**The problem** lies with the label and how it's listed in my label list database.

***example:*** `\zhf{FileLocation}{xpicture}`
my label list has "fig_  #3" instead of listing "fig_ xpicture"

I'm new to latex, any help would be appreciated and if there's a better method to confronting this problem, i'd be glad to hear it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\zfh}[3][2in]{
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}
           \includegraphics[height= #1]{./FT/#2}
        \end{center}
        \caption{\protect\detokenize{#3}}
        \label{fig_  #3}
    \end{figure}
    }

    \zfh{zzz.pdf}{XCaption}

    \ref{fig_  #3}  % fig_ #3 is listed instead of the actual text inserted as the #3 arg
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterGrill has answered the question but it's best not to use a space in the ref argument so I would use `fig_#3` and `ref{fig_XCaption}`without a space in both cases. Also you should use `\centering` rather than `\begin{center}` in this context to avoid extra vertical space, and finally it is best not to use `[H]` which is only really as a last-resort final edit for difficult figures, it should never be used as here hidden in another markup for a range of figures.

Comment: Also the `\protect\detokenize` is nothing I would recommend.

Comment: what you had in mind with `\ref{fig_  #3}` is not possible. #3 is not known outside of `\zfh`

Comment: @Herbert: thanks, I thought so, but i thought i'd ask before I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

To fix you main problem you need to use `\ref{fig_  XCaption}` to refer to the figure.  The second optional parameter to `\zfh` is what is used for the label, so that is what needs to be used in the `\ref{}`, not `#3`.

In the MWE below, I have incorporated the suggestions of David Carlisle and egreg:

- Used `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables).
- Removed the space in the figure label.
- Removed the `[H]` placement option. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)
- Removed the `\protect\detokenize`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newcommand{\zfh}[3][2in]{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height= #1]{./FT/#2}
        \caption{#3}
        \label{fig_#3}
    \end{figure}
    }

\begin{document}
    \zfh{zzz.pdf}{XCaption}

    See Figure~\ref{fig_XCaption}  % Figure 1 is inserted as desired
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although the tips are thoughtful, it's not the main problem. 
The code, with it's lack of efficiency, worked. 

**The problem is** the fact that my label database/collection has "fig_#3" instead of "fig_XCaption" listed.
I can very well type \ref{fig_XCaption}, but that would suck out most of the handyness of latex documents...

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `#3` refers to the third parameter of a macro and does not exist outside of the macro. If you move the `\ref{fig_#3}` to be in the `\zfh` then you can use `#3`, but that isn't of much use. Perhaps if you explained exactly what you are trying to do, then someone here might be able to provide a suggestion for improvement.

Comment: @Zlaid: Basically, the question is to know how TeX should choose which figure to refer to: what happens if you have more than one instance of `\zfh`?

Comment: Even after invoking \zfh twice, my label database only references fig_ #3. 

for say: \zfh{xfile.pdf}{Xpic}\zfh{yfile.pdf}{Ypic}

my database/list of labels list only fig_ #3. And the nice popup menu that shows up when i usually \ref something, doesnt include fig_Xpic nor fig_Ypic, only fig_ #3.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using some kind of intelligent editor that tries to find
`\label` commands in the TeX source and offer a list of label names if you
are typing `\ref`. The problem is that the `\label` occurs inside a definition
and your editor only sees `\label{fig_#3}`, but ignores the calls of
`\zfh`. Your editor is not TeX, thus it does not know that \newcommands
starts a definition and that it must replace `#3` by the third argument.
I do not know, which editor you are using, but I have some doubts that it can be taught easily, how to deal with `\zfh`. But maybe you can trick your editor by changing the
way, `\zfh` is called and also the `\label` inside the definition can perhaps be hidden.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand*{\RemoveFigPrefix}{}%
\def\RemoveFigPrefix#1_{}

\newcommand*{\zfh}[2][2in]{%
  \zfhLabel{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\zfhLabel}{}
\edef\zfhLabel{%
  \def\noexpand\zfhLabel##1##2%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname label\endcsname
}\zfhLabel#3{%
  \begin{figure}[H]% see comments
    \centering % see comments
    \includegraphics[height=#1]{./FT/#2}
    \caption{\RemoveFigPrefix#3}
    \csname label\endcsname{#3}%
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}

  \listoffigures

  \section*{Section with figures}

  \zfh[1in]{zzz.pdf}\label{fig_XCaption}

  \zfh[1in]{foo.pdf}\label{fig_YPic}

  Two figures \ref{fig_XCaption} and \ref{fig_YPic}.

\end{document}
```

Some explanations:

- Some macro definitions are done using TeX's `\def`, because it allows more powerful parameter texts. But it does not check, whether the command is already defined, it
  just overwrites a previous meaning of the macro. Therefore the `\newcommand` lines
  are added that give LaTeX a chance to issue an error message, if the macro is already defined.
- The `\label` inside the definition is hidden using `\csname` and `\endcsname`.
  These commands construct command tokens:

  ```
  \csname label\endcsname => \label
  ```
- If the editor reads `\zfh{...}{...}\label{...}` then it will understand `\label{...}`. But we want to
  reuse the argument of `\label` for the caption. Therefore the `\label{...}` is a
  required part of the syntax of `\zfh` and gets consumed during the execution of `\zfh`.
  Nevertheless `\zfh` will eventually call `\label{...}`.
- To make the definition of `\zfh` easier, the definition is split up in two macros.
  The first scans for the optional argument and the first mandatory argument;
  the second macro `\zfhLabel` takes care of the `\label{...}` part. In the definition
  of `\zfhLabel` there is another `\label` that might confuse the editor (Or not,
  because the curly braces are missing, but who knows for sure?):

  ```
  \def\zfhLabel#1#2\label#3{%
  ```

  This is obfuscated by

  ```
  \edef\zfhLabel{%
    \def\noexpand\zfhLabel##1##2%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname label\endcsname
  }\zfhLabel#3{%
  ```

  There is no need to understand this for a beginner. The more experienced will see that the first definition of `\zfhLabel` is just a temporary definition that constructs
  the part of the final definition of `\zfhLabel`.

Let's us hope that your editor now finds all correct `\label` commands with the changes
in the TeX source code above, ignores the
`\label` inside definitions and presents you a complete label list, if you want to reference a figure.